# Unable to write parquet data on local using spark by appending timestamp at the end

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to append the `timestamp/date` string at the end of the `destination` path but it fails. If I remove, then there is no error. I tried below things:

```
val formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:ss")
val newDate = formatDate.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
val finalPath = jobInfo.jobId + "_" + jobInfo.jobRunId + "_" + newDate
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(destPath + "\\" + cTableName + "\\" + finalPath.trim())
```

Error:

```
java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/C:/tmp/sparkIF/employees/1000_12_2020-31-18 08:11/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20200318203112_0002_m_000000_2
```

As I can see it is trying to create `temporary` directories. I am not sure why it is doing so. Since, I am using `overwrite` mode existing directories shouldn't be a problem

Comment: `:` not supported maybe.

Comment: I checked some answers and they said by changing the version of `fileoutputcommiter` class to 2 I should be able to write it but no luck. It was actually suggested while submitting job but I am running it directly as of now. Any help with that?

Comment: I mean windows os didn't allow the character as filename.

Comment: Can you suggest something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop do not support semicolon in the directory path

Below Code should work

```
val finalPath = jobInfo.jobId + "_" + jobInfo.jobRunId + "_" + newDate.replaceAll(":","_")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think problem in your example in space symbol in path. Better way to save data depends on date using directory date partitioning. Look for example:

```
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
val datePartitions = Seq(
  s"year=${cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)}",
  s"month=${"%02d".format(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH))}",
  s"day=${"%02d".format(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))}",
  s"hour=${"%02d".format(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR))}",
  s"minute=${"%02d".format(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE))}"
).mkString(File.separator)
val finalPath = s"${jobId}_$jobRunId${File.separator}$datePartitions"
println(s"$destPath${File.separator}$cTableName${File.separator}$finalPath")
// it prints your prefix and year=2020\month=02\day=19\hour=10\minute=03 suffix
```